# Video responsive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have inserted a video responsive on blogger in this way.

CSS

```
.flex-video {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 67.5%;
 height: 0;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-video.widescreen { padding-bottom: 57.25%; }
.flex-video.vimeo { padding-top: 0; }

 .flex-video iframe,
 .flex-video object,
 .flex-video embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px), only screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 600px), only screen and (width: 1280px) and (orientation: landscape), only screen and (device-width: 800px), only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .flex-video { padding-top: 0; }
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('iframe').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="flex-video"></div>');
      });
});
```

Now I have insert a jQuery animation for hiding video, following this tutorial.

http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/title/show-hide-div-jquery.html

The jquery effect works, but in this way the video isn't responsive.

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Here it is :) https://jsfiddle.net/yn7q9ys5/

If you resize the output, the first video doesn't resize it. Click on the "Click here" button for show the first video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `div#wr` has fixed width. Just remove it, e.g.

```
#wr {
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Also, your jQuery code can be simplified to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('iframe').each(function () {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="flex-video"></div>');
    });

    if ($('div.trigger')) {
        $('div.trigger').click(function (e) {
            $(this).toggleClass('open')
                .toggleClass('close')
                .next()
                .slideToggle(100);

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
```

Full code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/5okxmr9k/)

Answer (score 0):

use `max-width` instead `width`

https://jsfiddle.net/reeyz2Ly/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('iframe').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<div class="flex-video"></div>');
  });
}); 





$(document).ready(function() {
  
 if($('div.trigger').length > 0) {
  $('div.trigger').click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
    $(this).removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass('close');
    $(this).next().slideDown(100);
    return false;
   } else {
    $(this).removeClass('close');
    $(this).addClass('open');
    $(this).next().slideUp(100);
    return false;
   }   
  });
 }
 
});
```

```css
.flex-video {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 67.5%;
  height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-video.widescreen { padding-bottom: 57.25%; }
.flex-video.vimeo { padding-top: 0; }

.flex-video iframe,
.flex-video object,
.flex-video embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px), only screen and (device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 600px), only screen and (width: 1280px) and (orientation: landscape), only screen and (device-width: 800px), only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .flex-video { padding-top: 0; }
}





#wr {
 max-width:800px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: left;
}
.trigger,.trigger a {
 display: block;
 max-width: 680px;
 height: 100px;
 text-indent: -999999em;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.trigger {
 background: url(http://rtse.co.uk/images/clickhere.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
.close {
 background: url(http://i.imgur.com/J3iA56c.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}
.cnt {
 display: none;
}
.cl {
 width: 100%;
 clear: both;
 line-height: 0px;
 font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Responsive video doesn't work-->

<div id="wr">
<div class="trigger open"><a href="#">Open</a></div>
<div class="cnt">
<center><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/inrmCnUsdak?rel=0" width="640"></iframe></center>
</div></div>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<!--Responsive video works-->

<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/inrmCnUsdak?rel=0" width="640"></iframe>
```